# Python request malfunctioning

Tags: python, iframe, python-requests, findall

Help with python please. 
I have tried to scrape webpage using python. when I try to get iframe src in this url it gives me only one iframe source.

This is the webpage I tried to scrape.

Source 1

Source 2

Source 2

this is my python code:

```
iframe = re.compile( '<iframe.*src="(.*?)"' ).findall( html )
```

this one gives me only 1 iframe. But there are 4 iframes

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It is highly recommended to [*not* parse HTML with regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/670206). For Python, [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) is a widely used option that does this parsing for you.

For extracting your `<iframe/>` sources, you could use something like this

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

resp = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text)
for frame in soup.findAll('iframe'):
    print(frame['src'])
```

For the URL that you have specified, this will yield the following result

```
http://www.playhd.video/embed.php?vid=xxx
http://mersalaayitten.com/embed/xxx
http://www.playhd.video/embed.php?vid=xxx
http://googleplay.tv/videos/kanithan?iframe=true
//www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fkathaltamilmovie&width=600&height=188&colorscheme=light&show_faces=true&header=false&stream=false&show_border=true
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the four that are together, you can get the data from the second table which holds the four iframes using  [BeautifulSoup css-selectors](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors), in particular `nth-of-type(2)` to pull the second table :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

html = requests.get("http://kathaltamil.com/?v=Kanithan").content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

urls = [ifr["src"] for ifr in soup.select("table:nth-of-type(2)")[0].select("iframe")]
```

Which will give you just the four:

```
['http://www.playhd.video/embed.php?vid=621', 
'http://mersalaayitten.com/embed/3752', 
'http://www.playhd.video/embed.php?vid=584', 
'http://googleplay.tv/videos/kanithan?iframe=true']
```

Or even easier with [lxml](http://lxml.de/) and xpath:

```
import requests

html = requests.get("http://kathaltamil.com/?v=Kanithan").content


from lxml.etree import fromstring, HTMLParser

xml = fromstring(html, HTMLParser())

print(xml.xpath("//table[2]//iframe/@src"))
```

Which gives you the same:

```
['http://www.playhd.video/embed.php?vid=621',
 'http://mersalaayitten.com/embed/3752', 
'http://www.playhd.video/embed.php?vid=584', 
'http://googleplay.tv/videos/kanithan?iframe=true']
```

Whatever you choose is going to be a better option than your regex.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you forgot a question mark (`?`) after the first .*
The correct way would be so:

```
iframe = re.compile( '<iframe.*?src="(.*?)"' ).findall( html )
```

Overall though, keep in mind regexes are not a good way for parsing html webpages. Beautiful soup, lxml, scrapy, and other libraries will be more efficient and powerfull.